# File based caching with expiration in python

Tags: python, caching

To generate stats I'm doing a few 100 XMLRPC requests to a 3rd party API.

As I want to have the stats computed fast to be able to play with it, I want to cache the responses from the API.

An excerpt of the APIs HTTP headers:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "c539d317b07c640c123e287304d2c568"
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID ADMa OPTa OUR NOR"
Content-Length: 4089
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

I need:

- a solution for python 2.6
- as the API responses are fairly big, the cache should be written on disk (no in memory caching)
- I want to expire the api responses e.g. after 1 day
- old responses on the disc should be deleted to not have an endlessly growing cache

I am close to write something my own as it doesn't seem to be too complex but I thought this might be a quite common use case so there might be something existing already.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since nobody came up with a good existing module, I have written one myself.

Not particularly pretty but it does the job I think. Feedback very much welcome

http://pastie.org/2842063